# Add list of abbreviations to table of contents

Tags: acro

I use the `acro` package for abbreviations in my thesis. How can I add the list of abbreviations to the table of contents?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{bla}{
  short = BLA,
  long = BBBLLLAAA,
  class = A
}

\DeclareAcronym{foo}{
  short = FOO,
  long = FFFOOOOOO,
  class = B
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\printacronyms[include-classes=A,name=Abbreviations]
\printacronyms[include-classes=B,name=Nomenclature]

\ac{bla}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place the command `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}` on the line above your `\printacronyms[include-classes=A,name=Abbreviations]`.

Changing the `{section}` to `{chapter}` will change the TOC entry so it looks like a chapter rather than a section.

`List of Abbreviations` can be replaced by what you want your entry to be called.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{bla}{
  short = BLA,
  long = BBBLLLAAA,
  class = A
}

\DeclareAcronym{foo}{
  short = FOO,
  long = FFFOOOOOO,
  class = B
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\printacronyms[include-classes=A,name=Abbreviations]
\printacronyms[include-classes=B,name=Nomenclature]

\ac{bla}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How could I include the list of abbreviations in such a way that it resembles my list of figures and tables (with the same format as \makelistoftables and \makelistoffigures). I want roman numbers instead of Arabic numbers and bold font in the table of contents. The codes you posted above it shows Arabic numbers and normal font. I do not want it to look like a chapter, section, or subsection, but like the \makelistoftables or \makelistoffigures commands.